# How to use colors of my choice for plotting by groups in R?

Tags: r, plot, colors

I have a column (named group) as grouping information (1 to 4 for 4 groups) and I wish to use this to assign different colors to the groups in a plot

```
x=data.frame(read.csv(file.choose()))
plot(x$A,x$B,col=as.factor(x$group))
```

This gives the colors as black, red, green and so on for groups marked as 1, 2, 3 ... respectively. How do I modify the code if I wish to asign the colours according to my desire. Lets say I want the group marked as 1 to be displayed in blue color (for example)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Like this:

```
plot(Sepal.Length ~ Sepal.Width, data = iris, 
     col = c("blue", "red", "green")[as.factor(Species)])
legend("topright", pch = 1, col = c("blue", "red", "green"),
       legend = levels(as.factor(iris$Species)))
```